# Remote Ubuntu Install

Tags: installation, server, remote

How would I go about installing Ubuntu Server on a remote dedicated server?
I am not sure whether it has pre-existing OS on it or not.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question.

I would go with pxeboot, if you are going to do this often.

Here is the documentation.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallMultiDistro

If not.

I would see if the server has a Remote Management Port, or Console connection. Then get someone to burn and insert the Ubuntu CD or USB. Then connect over this to do the install.

Comment: The PXE guide looks a bit outdated. It uses Ubuntu 9.10.